# Android 2D graphic library

Tags: android, graphics

I can not figure out the android 2D graphic library. Is it **SGL**, **Skia** or subset of **OpenGL**

Answer (score 5):

There's Android's own [Drawable and Canvas APIs](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+2d+graphics), as well as [OpenGL ES](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Google has this resource: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html

Answer (score 1):

For 2d rendering android uses `sgl` which is nothing but `skia` or scalable graphics library